# rscala invoke exception. Can't find package

Tags: scala

I am getting the following error in my implementation of rscala

> Error in library(gmodels) : there is no package called 'gmodels'

the r function is tested and works. It includes a call to library(gmodels).

The rscala code is as follows

```
val rc = RClient()
val category= rc.invokeS0("doPredictionSVM","lemmas"->"Communicate,Design,Java,Code,Sql,Database,Computer,Web,Network,Source,Work,","frequency"->"3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this solution works, but I found I have to invoke the package declarations in scala as well:

```
rc eval """
library(gmodels, lib.loc="C:\\Users\\jake\\Documents\\R\\win-library\\3.3")
"""
```

Problem solved, but not fully understood. Further explanation would be most welcome